# etc folder outside root

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm currently working for a client who has a magento 1.7 version and the etc folder has been put outside the root. 
Is there any reason other than security to do it? Is not safe enough to have etc folder under app?
thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's the same etc folder you're thinking of?

Comment: yeah, app/etc. Inside there is the modules folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the `.htaccess` file remains in tact under `app/` reading it from the web is not easily possible.

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/.htaccess

I don't see much advantage security wise other than adding unnecessary complexity, perhaps obscurity since its not standard may be the only advantage.